# Spring Boot Starters for Azure java 11

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-java-sdk, spring-boot-starter

I was following this document from Microsoft on spring boot on Azure, which state that I must use java 8 and not java 11 in order to use Spring Boot Starters for Azure, from the doc:
"Spring Initializr uses Java 11 as the default version. To use the Spring Boot Starters described in this topic, you must select Java 8 instead",
doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starters-for-azure

in Azure SDK docs for java/spring boot it says:
Java Development Kit (JDK) with version 8 or above

The question is can I use spring boot with java 11 on Azure with or without spring boot starters?
it seems to work as Azure supports java 11.

thanks,
Liav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use spring boot with java 11 on Azure with or without spring
> boot starters?

Yes. Azure supports spring boot with java 11.

The article walks you through deploying a Spring Boot app to Azure, see [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/).

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, according to Microsoft they will soon change the documentation from java 8 to java 11.